# Django: Is there a way to let Heroku manage js and css files but let images come from S3 bucket?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, heroku, django-staticfiles

I am buiding an app with django. I uploaded all my static files to an S3 bucket. Js and css files included. And in DEBUG = False I'm getting my files from that bucket

I am hosting my app in Heroku, so I couldn't serve images from there. That's way I'm getting my images from an externar source.

But now I'm facing some problems when I have all my files in the S3 bucket. And I also think it's not really necessary to serve js and css from there too.

So i**s there a way to let images come from the S3 bucket but serve my js and css files from the host** (heroku)?

Comment: Do you mean uploaded images, or images from your static files?

Comment: @markwalker_ I mean images from my static files

Comment: I've never heard of this being done, so to do that, I think you'd need to write your own static files storage class.

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file `remove` the following line

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

And `keep` the following line

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

By doing this your js and css will not be served from your S3 bucket

Comment: I don't think this is what they're looking for. They want a static files storage class which supports different locations for different types of files.